# Директория гита представлена некорректно

Tags: git, git-commit, git-push

У меня есть папка с сайтом, которая называется Ведьмак. Я хочу, чтобы когда я что-то изменил, то я мог увидеть это через git status и создать коммит, запушить в репозиторий.

Но когда я жму git status, у меня выводятся красным совершенно другие файлы, которых нет в этой папке. Какие-то системные. Как сделать, чтобы отслеживалась нужная мне папка?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/715321/5752652

Answer (score 2):

Если вы находитесь уже в нужной папке, то дайте команду

```
git status .
```

Либо же укажите нужный каталог:

```
git status <directoryPath>
```

Отсюда: https://stackoverflow.com/q/715321/5752652

Также нужно понимать, что вы определитесь: либо у вас отдельный сайт -- это отдельный репозиторий, либо у вас один репозиторий на все сделанные сайты (тогда инструкция выше).
Вкладывать же репозиторий в репозиторий нельзя (за исключением [submodules](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1093332/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d0%be%d1%82-20-%d0%b4%d0%be-20-%d1%81-%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bc-0-2), не думаю, что вам подойдёт)

Comment: Мой бог... Это не SitesThatsDone является репозиторием, это весь профиль пользователя засунут в гит, да ещё и без исключений, вон даже AppData светится...

Comment: Так да, я же поэтому и скрин и скинул, вот init в папке помогло

Comment: Нда, формально -- помогло, а по сути вы просто не понимаете, что у вас есть огромнейший на несколько мегабайт репозиторий с лишними файлами. Зачем вам гит на весь профиль пользователя?

Comment: @shadow1337 Папку `.git`, которая в `C:\Users\<username>` - в мусор.

Comment: Да я просто не совсем силен в этом, только начинаю разбираться, я не знаю, как так вышло, что был тот репозиторий инициализирован. На гитхабе в папке нужные файлы (/kava13/kava13/the_witcher). Ладно, попробую удалить репозиторий и заново создать, может меньше проблем будет)

Comment: Гм. Если речь про этот репозиторий: https://github.com/kava13/the_witcher то там всё правильно и аккуратно. Только 28 дней назад разве что был последний коммит, а так норм, только папка ведьмака. А вот репозитория на много гигов там нет, поэтому вполне вероятно вы его не отправляли на гитхаб. Поэтому совет просто удалить папку `.git`, которая в `C:\Users\<username>` -- очень хороший совет. И не надо делать необратимых действий типа удаления репозитория. Положите в корзину, посмотрите, если что потом вернёте куда-нибудь в архив.

Comment: Создать такую репу было просто запустив cmd и дав команду git init -- по умолчанию открывается как раз папка профиля пользователя.

Answer (score 0):

А ты сделал git init в папке проекта ?

1. `cd /path/to/my/codebase`
2. `git init`
3. `git add .`
4. `git commit`

Comment: Вот теперь да, сделал все по порядку из этих пунктов, но при git push пишет:

$ git push
fatal: No configured push destination.
Either specify the URL from the command-line or configure a remote repository using

    git remote add <name> <url>

and then push using the remote name

    git push <name>

Comment: Как по мне -- это совершенно не ответ, т.к. понятно по untracked files что где-то каталогом выше был инициализирован репозиторий. Предыдущая версия ответа была больше похожа на комментарий, поэтому я её перенёс в комментарии, но после исправления стало больше похоже на попытку угадать ответ, так что восстановил -- а правильно или неправильно решать не буду.